# Spring Boot REST - Ambiguous mapping even with unique path variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two endpoints with a different set of path variables. They both work unless I give an optional parameter `(name)` in the URL. Then Spring gives ambiguous error.

The optional parameter `name` is also present in the second endpoint which is why the error happens.

**Why does Spring think these endpoints are ambiguous?**

Required parameters should make the endpoints unique (because first endpoint contains parameter "sourceid" and the second one does not). The following URL gives the error:

*/?sourceid=999&applicantid=1&startingdate=2020&endingdate=2021&**name=mobileapp***

**First Endpoint:**

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/", params= {"sourceid", "applicantid", "startingdate", "endingdate"})
public List<Event> getEventsById(
        @RequestParam("sourceid") String sourceid,
        @RequestParam("applicantid") String applicantid,
        @RequestParam("startingdate") String startingdate,
        @RequestParam("endingdate") String endingdate,
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {
```

**Second Endpoint:**

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/", params= { "name", "applicantid", "startingdate", "endingdate"})
public List<Event> getEventsByApplicantId(
        @RequestParam("applicantid") String applicantid,
        @RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("startingdate") String startingdate,
        @RequestParam("endingdate") String endingdate) {
```

Error Message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/event-example/': {public java.util.List com.eventrest.controller.MyController.getEventsById(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.text.ParseException, public java.util.List com.eventrest.controller.MyController.getEventsByApplicantId(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.text.ParseException}
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:413) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:367) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:59) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:396) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1234) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1016) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
```

Comment: I don't know if it would resolve your problem and I don't know if this is necessary for a non required param, but I see that "name" param is missing in the params of the first endpoint.

Comment: The endpoints are ambiguous. You must have unique request mappings disregarding the request params.

Comment: Those aren't path variables those are just regular request parameters. Please add the proper code (there appears to be a mismatch) and the actual exception.

Comment: @Gaetitan this did not work. If "name" parameter is added to params, it makes it required parameter and the URL no longer works without "name" parameter. Also if "name" parameter is included into URL, same ambiguous error shows up.

Comment: @M.Deinum what do you mean with mismatch? This is a bit simplified code, but the actual code is similar with just more parameters.

Comment: @SergVasylchak doesn't Spring look up the most matching method by parameter names that are given in URL? Do you mean, that GetMapping value must be different(it is now value="/")?

Comment: Yes, I do. The controller request mapping + request mapping value of each request method must be unique. This is the only way to fix the ambiguity. So you should change the value of one of the endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring can't distinguish if the request GET `http://localhost:8080/?sourceid=999&applicantid=1&startingdate=2020&endingdate=2021&name=mobileapp` will be handled by `getEventsById()` or by `getEventsByApplicantId()` because your mapping is ambiguous.

Consider that the `sourceid` is `required = false` **in the second method** as **in the first method**, naturally these two methods are the same.

#### There is a way out of ambiguous.

> You can narrow request mappings based on request parameter conditions. You can test for the presence of a request parameter (myParam), for the absence of one (!myParam), or for a specific value (myParam=myValue). [Read Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers)

Add `!sourceid` to the **params field** in your `getEventsByApplicantId()` method as follows:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/", params= {"!sourceid", "name", "applicantid", "startingdate", "endingdate"})
public List<Event> getEventsByApplicantId(
        @RequestParam("applicantid") String applicantid,
        @RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("startingdate") String startingdate,
        @RequestParam("endingdate") String endingdate) {
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Such a simple solution that I did not come across even with a few days of furious googling. I think my googling skills (search word combinations) needs a little refinement. Thank you!